# Rails asset pipeline + knockout.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, knockout.js, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to implement knockout.js in Rails 3.2.6. I'm using the Gem https://github.com/jswanner/knockoutjs-rails.

I'm having trouble loading the ViewModel.

Here's my HTML for debugging

```
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(users)"></div>
```

Here's the JavaScript compiled from CoffeeScript. The file is `users.js.coffee` and is included in the asset pipeline via `//= require_tree .` in `application.js`

```
(function() {

  jQuery(function() {
    var User, UserViewModel;    
    User = function(id, name) {
      var self;
      self = this;
      self.id = ko.observable(id);
      self.name = ko.observable(name);
      return self.followers_count_message = ko.computed(function() {});
    };
    UserViewModel = function() {
      var self;
      self = this;
      self.users = ko.observableArray([new User('1111', 'test name'), new User('1112', 'test name2')]);
      self.addUsers = function() {
        return self.users.push(new User('1113', 'test name'));
      };
      return self.addUsers();
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new UserViewModel());
    return alert('done');
  });

}).call(this);
```

Upon loading, the div displays this: `[null,null,null]`

The odd thing is if I implement this in jsFiddle, it seems to work. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/netwire88/HXYHU/2/

Thoughts, ideas?

**UPDATE: 7/31/2012**

I was able to fix this by changing the functions to remove the `return`. However, I would like to move it to another CoffeeScript file.

I tried this in `users.js.coffee`, however, I'm getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null`

```
User = (id, name) ->
  self = undefined
  self = this
  self.id = ko.observable(id)
  self.name = ko.observable(name)
  @

UserViewModel = ->
  self = this
  self.users = ko.observableArray([new User("1111", "test name"), new User("1112", "test name2")])
  self.addUsers = ->
    self.users.push new User("1113", "test name")
  self.addUsers()
  @

ko.applyBindings new UserViewModel()
```

Comment: put your User object and your viewmodel to your application.js. you don't need the jquery call stuff for a test. knockouts run without jquery.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but that didn't seem to work. Something is causing the binding to not work correctly.

Comment: Actually @dean, it doesn't work in fiddle if you use this whole thing. I don't think this is a knockout issue, I think its a coffeescript issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should notice a very, *very* important difference between the code you posted, and the code in the fiddle: your viewmodels return single properties, the fiddle's viewmodels have no return.

Your code is creating invalid viewmodels. If you uncomment those returns in your fiddle, it breaks in exactly the same way. You didn't post the coffeescript for us to look at, but this is definitely the issue.

Bad Viewmodel:

```
User = function(id, name) {
      var self;
      self = this;
      self.id = ko.observable(id);
      self.name = ko.observable(name);
      return self.followers_count_message = ko.computed(function() {});
    };
```

Good Viewmodel

```
User = function(id, name) {
      var self;
      self = this;
      self.id = ko.observable(id);
      self.name = ko.observable(name);
    };
```

Same goes for the `UserViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. CoffeeScript adds a default return to every function, should I just use "@" to "return this"?